# I got error when trying to run docker-compose up --build. And i got an error in my sql seed data

Tags: postgresql

I got this error while trying to run `docker-compose up --build`, I'm using postgresql as my database service. I think there's wrong with my query.When i remove the `CREATE TRIGGER` it somehow run without erros.

```
LINE 13:            CREATE TRIGGER update_communication
backend-postgres-1 |^
```

Here is my sql file

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dts.save_communication_revision()
  RETURNS TRIGGER 
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
  AS
$$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dts.communication_revisions(com_id, class_id, com_subject, user_id, com_source_name, "com_dateCreated", "com_dateReceived", com_urgency, com_source_position, com_source_office, com_draft, com_other_remarks, "com_controlNo", com_due_date)
    VALUES(OLD.com_id, OLD.class_id, OLD.com_subject, OLD.user_id, OLD.com_source_name, OLD."com_dateCreated", OLD."com_dateReceived", OLD.com_urgency, OLD.com_source_position, OLD.com_source_office, OLD.com_draft, OLD.com_other_remarks, OLD."com_controlNo", OLD.com_due_date);
END;
$$


CREATE TRIGGER update_communication
   AFTER UPDATE
   ON dts.communications
   FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE dts.save_communication_revision();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
END;
$$;
```

Just added this semicolon.